# Using final-form-array in a nested object

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have a scenario where I have multiple grids and in each grid can have multiple rows that can be deleted.

```
{ 
document: [{
rows: [{
make: "Tesla"
}]
}
```

I wanted to do something like `<FieldArray name="document[0]">` that way, I can give the grid add and remove functionality but it seems the fieldarray only takes single nodes. Is there a work around for this or am i doing something wrong?

Initially I had `document1: { [{...fields}] }` so useField looked like this:

```
useField(`${fieldKey}${fieldIndex}[${rowIndex}].${field}`)
```

but I wanted to use yup schema validations due to issues with ag-grid and validations at the cell level so I figured it'd be easier if I used generic keys.

```
fields.removeBatch(gridApi.getSelectedNodes().map(({ rowIndex }) => rowIndex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the wrong path. I needed to use

```
<FieldArray name={`${fieldKey}.${fieldIndex}.rows`}>
```

This matched the new structure. So FieldArray does support nested objects, you just need to get the names right.

Comment: You got it!! 